# How do you find the average of a list with numbers in quotes, in python?

Tags: python, linux, unix

I have two types of lists. The first **without** quotes, which **works** and prints the average fine:

```
l = [15,18,20]
print l
print "Average: ", sum(l)/len(l)
```

This prints:

```
[15,18,20]
Average: 17
```

The second list has numbers **with** quotes, which returns an **error**:

```
x = ["15","18","20"]
print x
print "Average: ", sum(x)/len(x)
```

The Error is:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

How do you calculate a list with number values within quotes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The quotes mean that you have a list of strings:

```
>>> x = ["15","18","20"]
>>> type(x[0])
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

`sum` only works with lists of numbers (integers such as `1` or floats such as `1.0`).

To fix your problem, you must first convert your list of strings into a list of integers.  You can use the built-in [`map` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) for this:

```
x = ["15","18","20"]
x = map(int, x)
```

Or, you could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (which many Python programmers prefer):

```
x = ["15","18","20"]
x = [int(i) for i in x]
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> x = ["15","18","20"]
>>> x = map(int, x)
>>> x
[15, 18, 20]
>>> type(x[0])
<type 'int'>
>>> sum(x) / len(x)
17
>>>
```

Comment: Brilliant, I've been scratching my head for ages. Thanks mate! @iCodez

Answer (score 3):

you need to convert them to `int` first:

```
x = ["15","18","20"]
print sum(map(int,x))/len(x)
```

here `map` will map every element of x to integer type

Comment: Back again! Thanks for the help mate, this works just fine. @Hackaholic

Answer (score 2):

```
print "Average of {list} is: {avg}".format(
    list=l,
    avg=sum(int(x) for x in l) / len(l),
)
```

Comment: You need to remember to divide by the `len` of the list